# In mysql, how can I select the numeric portion of a field?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table containing free-form phone numbers (e.g. '123-456-7890', '(987) 654-3210', or '123.456.7890') and I'm searching them with a numeric string- e.g., '123456'.

Right now, I'm having to do a bunch of replace(replace(replace(.. ad nauseum functions to strip out errant non-numeric characters then use that 'LIKE' the search value to search.

Anyone know of a simpler way to select only certain characters from a field based on type, not position?

Comment: Not an answer, but you should standardize the way you store phone numbers in your database.

Comment: *nod* No argument here. I inherited the database, the monkey, and the circus, so it's now my problem. ;)

Comment: As a temporary solution you could add a column with standardized numbers. Otherwise I wouldn't know :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex in MySQL -

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `phone` REGEXP '^[12345]'
```

Here is a working [**example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58d6a/18).

Comment: I looked at regexp, but I'm not looking to see which fields are numeric, I'm trying to match a pattern against only the numeric portion of the field. e.g., '12345' matches '123-456-7890' and '(123) 456-7890'. Right now I'm peeling non-numeric characters off the phone field with REPLACE() and doing a compare with LIKE to the entered search string.

Comment: The regex performed here removes the special characters withouot replacing them so that a comparison can be done. '12345' does not match '1234567890' unless you're wanting to search for partial numerical strings. Am I missing something?

Comment: '%12345%' like '1234567890' does match. Perhaps I should have been clearer. I need to select the numeric portion, then do a LIKE comparison on it. 1/0 as to whether it contains any digits doesn't really help me do the comparison to the search string.

Edit: your updated query generates an error, I don't think REGEXP is doing what you think it is. It just returns 0/1 -- is pattern matched, yes or no.

Comment: I updated to fit your requirements @TXTurner Kep in mind that the regex can be modified easily should the conditions change.

Comment: Umm.. No, that's not quite right either. That matches on any number that contains 1,2,3,4,or 5. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Like I said, you might have tweak the regex, but I'm sure that you could have your exact needs met.

Comment: @TXTurner With some effort You can use the REGEX instead of `LIKE`, for example to search a phone number `LIKE '1234%'`, instead use `REGEXP '^[^[:digit:]]*1[^[:digit:]]*2[^[:digit:]]*3[^[:digit:]]*4.*'
`.

Answer (score 0):

try using regexes. if you want to extarct numbers from a string you can use this:

```
$string = '123-456-7890';
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $string, $matches);
echo $matches;    //will result in only digits
```

Comment: They are searching a database by a value. They haven't received the table row yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting up the number into three different values, i.e.

```
$first = '124';
$second= '456';
$third = '7890';

"WHERE (phone_number LIKE '%$first%' and LIKE '%$second%' and LIKE '%$third%')"
```

I'm not certain this is as effective as SQL's `REGEXP`, but it should work since every part is sectioned out. May not work if a number is like this in the db:`1245667890` because you can find `124`,`456`, and `7890`, but the number does not match. This answer assumes there will never be a solid number.